# How to prove $\frac{(-1)^{(n-1)}}n-1$ is Cauchy

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So I've got to prove $\frac{(-1)^{(n-1)}}n-1$ is a Cauchy sequence, but I can't do that if I can't simplify it to the point at which 1 is the numerator (so I can cross multiply with $\frac{2}{\epsilon}$), which I'm not sure you can.

I get as far as $|\frac{n+(-1)^n}{n}|+|\frac{m+(-1)^m}{m}| < \epsilon$ but have no idea how to simplify further.

Comment: Prove that it converges.Every convergent sequence is cauchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a_n = \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} - 1$

Pick some $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $$|a_n - a_m|$$
$$ = \Big |\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} - 1 - \frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{m} + 1\Big|$$
$$ = \Big|\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}  - \frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{m}\Big| $$
$$\leq \Big|\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} \Big | + \Big |\frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{m} \Big|$$
$$ = \Big| \frac{1}{n} \Big| + \Big| \frac{1}{m} \Big|$$

Given any $\epsilon > 0$, choose $N = 2 * \lceil \frac{1}{\epsilon} \rceil$ so that $n, m > N$ $\implies $

$$|a_n - a_m| \leq \Big| \frac{1}{n} \Big| + \Big| \frac{1}{m} \Big| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$$

Comment: So you can just simplify $(-1)^{n-1}$ to 1?

Comment: $(-1)^{n-1}$ is either $-1$ or $+1$ so $|(-1)^{n-1}|$ is always $1$.

Comment: Also, $\Big | \frac{a}{b} \Big | = \frac{|a|}{|b|}  = \Big | \frac{a}{|b|} \Big | = \Big | \frac{|a|}{b} \Big |   $ if that's what is confusing you.

Comment: Thanks! All good now.

Answer (score 1):

$$\left|\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}-1 - \frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{m}+1\right| \leq 2 \max\left\{\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{m}\right\},$$ hence if $n,m > \frac{2}{\epsilon}$, you have $$\left|\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} - \frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{m}\right| < \epsilon.$$